# How to combine two SQL tables in codeigniter without using SQL queries?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Here is my codes,

```
//FROM MY CONTROLLER

$companies = $this->Uploads_model->getallcompanies();
$general = $this->Uploads_model->getallcontract();

$this->data['companieslist'] = $companies; 
$this->data['uploads'] = $general;

$this->render('contracts/index_view');

// MY VIEW
foreach($companieslist as $company){
    $general_c[] = $company->company_id;
    $general_c[] = $company->company_name;
}

foreach ( $uploads as $key => $con ) { 
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <label class="pos-rel">
                <input type="checkbox" class="ace"/>
                <span class="lbl"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">
            <?php 
                if($con->Company_id == $general_c[$company_id]){  // MY QUESTION IS HERE
                    echo $con->Company_name;
                }
            ?>
            </a>
        </td>
```

So, am working on this web app where am supposed to display in table all contract files followed with company owned this contract.
I have two tables in my Database as follow `Companies_tbl` and `contract_tbl`.
I have `Company_id` as a foreign key in `contract_tbl`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom function to filter your contracts based on `Company_id`

```
function getContractsForId($contracts,$Company_id) {
  return array_filter($contracts,function(){
      return $contracts->Company_id === $Company_id;
  });
}
```

template loop:

```
foreach( getContractsForId($uploads,$Company_id) as $key => $con) {
//...html...
//remove the if
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not building the array of companies the right way.

```
foreach($companieslist as $company){
    $general_c[] = $company->company_id;
    $general_c[] = $company->company_name;
}
```

After you looped once, the `$general_c` array will look like this:

```
$general_c = [
    0 => 1, //company id
    1 => 'Company name'
]
```

After the second time:

```
$general_c = [
    0 => 1, //company id
    1 => 'Company name',
    2 => 2, //company id
    3 => 'Company name 2'
]
```

What you want is the following:

```
foreach($companieslist as $company){
    $general_c[$company->company_id] = $company->company_name;
}
```

And below:

```
<?php 
if($general_c[$con->Company_id]) {
    echo $general_c[$con->Company_id];
} ?>
```

This will let you output the company name based on ID.

But i suggest you do a MySQL join in your model. Add something like this to your `Uploads_model`:

```
function getContractsWithCompany() {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('contract_tbl')
            ->join('Companies_tbl', 'Companies_tbl.id = contract_tbl.Company_id')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to group files by `Company_id` then list the specific company files

```
$companies = $this->Uploads_model->getallcompanies();
$general = $this->Uploads_model->getallcontract();

$this->data['companieslist'] = $companies; 
$this->data['uploads'] = array();
//group file list by Company_id

foreach ($general as $key => $file) {
    if(!isset($this->data['uploads'][$file->Company_id ]))
         $this->data['uploads'][$file->Company_id] = array();
    $this->data['uploads'][$file->Company_id][] = $file;
}

// in your view
foreach($companieslist as $company){
    $general_c[] = $company->company_id;
    $general_c[] = $company->company_name;

    if(isset($uploads[$company->company_id])) {
        foreach ( $uploads[$company->company_id] as $key => $con ) {
            ?>
             <tr>
                <td class="center">
                    <label class="pos-rel">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="ace"/>
                        <span class="lbl"></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><?=$company->company_name?></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- and the rest of logic  -->

    <?php 
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is going to work out, because as far as i can tell the `$con` does only contain the FK `Company_id`. And not the company name (which he gets from the `$companieslist` array entries variable).

Comment: Table schema will help to get the right answer. Instead of $con->Company_name can be used $company->company_name